# How to insert multiple-line value into a yaml file with Pipeline Utility Steps plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, pipeline

in my jenkins pipeline I'm trying to edit a yaml file which let's say looks something like this

```
kind: food
    type: fruit
    stringData:
        fruits.yaml: |
            fruits:
                small:
                    berries:
                        color: blue
                        taste: good
                        continent: America
                        country: US
```

I need to edit something in fruits.yaml so I firstly do

```
def firstFile = readYaml file: "firstFile.yaml"
def secondFile = readYaml text: firstFile.stringData.'fruits.yaml'
secondFile.fruits.small.berries.color = purple
firstFile.stringData.'fruits.yaml' = secondFile
writeYaml overwrite: true, file: 'firstFile.yaml', data: firstFile
```

and the result looks like this

```
kind: food
    type: fruit
    stringData:
        fruits.yaml:
            fruits:
                small:
                    berries:
                        color: purple
                        taste: good
                        continent: America
                        country: US
```

as you can see, the value blue changed to purple, but what is now missing is the | symbol, which causes me trouble. Do you have any idea how to preserve it?

Comment: Convert second file to string using `writeYaml returnText:true` before assigning it into first.

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for. Thank you!